# Identificar os dias do mês a partir do número da semana PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um cadastro de eventos onde o usuário clica no dia desejado e aparece uma mensagem se ele deseja repetir esse evento para os outros dias da semana. Por ex.: se ele clicar no dia 11/10/2018 (quinta-feira), gostaria que ao selecionar essa opção, o cadastro se repetisse nos dias 18/10/2018 e 25/10/2018 que também são quinta-feira.

Entendo que pegar o dia da semana numérico, tenho que fazer dessa forma:

```
$diaSelecionado = $_POST["DiaSelecionado"]; // 11/10/2018
list($dia,$mes,$ano) = explode("/",$diaSelecionado);
$diaSemanaNumeral = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$mes,$dia,$ano));
```

Mas como eu poderia identificar as próximas quintas-feiras (ou qualquer outro dia da semana dependendo da data selecionada) e fazer o devido cadastro?

Comment: Qual o motivo de negativar o post?

Comment: tenho realmente percebido que muitas pessoas negativam perguntas pertinentes, que podem inclusive ajudar o site para esclarecer dúvidas a novos visitantes, sem qualquer motivo aparente. Isto é triste.

Comment: Minha opinião, quem negativa sem comentar é coisa de gente  que gosta de dissertar sobre o que não dizer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtotime — Interpreta qualquer descrição de data/hora em **texto em inglês** em timestamp Unix. Portanto temos que inverter o dia com o mês na data.

[exemplo ideone](https://ideone.com/HdxP1P)

```
//$diaSelecionado = $_POST["DiaSelecionado"]; // 11/10/2018

$diaSelecionado = '11/10/2018';

echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+1 week', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $diaSelecionado))));

echo PHP_EOL;

echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+2 week', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $diaSelecionado))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Soma 7 dias a data atual:

`date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+7 days'));`

E soma 7 dias a cada data gerada:

`echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+7 days', strtotime('18-10-2018')));`